# How to send output to a Text Area In HTML?

Tags: java, html, css, swing

I am developing a web-based POS,
I have a grid of items which can be purchased.

I want to display the name of the chosen Items
in a text area, as they are being selected.

How can I do that? Java Label? HTML Text Area? 
I am a bit lost.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: to much missing information to be answerable

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) on Oracle's site.  Intially you can set the text value in the constructor but as you add items to your transaction, you can use the append() method to add more lines to the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `JList` which will allow you to add items to a list.  It will also allow you to customise the way that the content is rendered as well.

[image: A List]

Take a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)